# Deleting an app from Apple app store and reuploading from another account

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, enterprise, itunes-store

I am trying to transfer an app on our iTunes store account to our client's account. But our client has a Enterprise account hence we cannot transfer it unless the client has a developer membership. But the client wants to distribute the app internally.

Can I delete the app from out store account and re-upload the same from the client's account?

If yes, what is the process I need to follow.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If they have an enterprise account then you can simply provide the source code and they can compile, sign and distribute the app themselves; no need to transfer the app in iTunesConnect. You can also make the app available from your account by making it a B2B app that they can acquire through the volume purchase program and distribute via their MDM

Comment: If your client wants to distribute internally, then no need to transfer. You can delete the App from AppStore and transfer the code to your client and he will compile with his Enterprise distribution profile(ENT2) and he can upload to it to any file host with this ENT2 provisioning.